# Screenshot of iCarousel/CATransform3D in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, screenshot, calayer, catransform3d

so the former approach using the undocumented API UIGetScreenImage is no longer accepted by Apple ( [Blog-post on UIGetScreenImage](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html) ).

The recommended [CALayer renderInContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html) approach doesn't work with 3D Animations as used in iCarousel.

Is there any currently allowed method of getting my iCarousel/CATransform3D-formed view into an UIImage?
Maybe is there a conversion from CATransform3D to CGAffineTransform (I know that this is generally not possible to, since CATransform3D has more dimensions, yet in the special case of the typical iCarousel, the full 3D-ness of CATransform3D isn't used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this thoroughly and ended up creating my own (simple) Carousel just using CGTransforms.